# When using OpenMP for C++, why is my CPU usage used almost exclusively by external calls when I declare a parallel loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, methods, parallel-processing, openmp

I am working on a program which although more complicated than the following, is the general gist of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
MethodA()
{
   for (int i=0; i < 10000; i++)
        methodB();
}

MethodB()
{
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i=0; i < length; i++)
        doSomeMath();

}
```

CPU Diagnoser in VS2022 is showing:

[image: CPU Diagnoser Image]

Without the parallel keyword, the CPU usage shows MethodA and MethodB as having the most usage. What is happening in this instance as I cannot determine the cause?

Comment: Look at the compiler output. https://godbolt.org/z/4Pefb1Mco OpenMP rewrites the code to call a library function ```_vcomp_fork``` with a function pointer to a helper function that does the actual work. That helper calls two more helper functions ```_vcomp_for_static_simple_init``` and ```..._end```. My best guess is that the parallelization overhead overshadows the work that you actually do. If you could get symbol names in your diagnoser, this would be clearer

Comment: To complete the comment of @Homer512, try with `#pragma omp parallel` in the function `MethodA` and `#pragma omp for` in the `MethodB` function. This should initialize the fork-join section only once (although clever OpenMP runtimes should already do it). You may need `#pragma omp single` or `#pragma omp master` in your more realistic code.